# Prolog: recursion is not working properly

Tags: recursion, prolog

I want to write `change_state(+L1, +L2, -L3).`

L1 contains states e.g: [milled, burned]
L2 contains predicates e.g: [del(milled), add(shifted)]
And L3 is the return list.

Example:

```
L1 = [milled, burned]
L2 = [del(burned), add(shifted)]
L3 = [milled, shifted]
```

So L1 is my start list and depending on the predicates in L2 I change the state of L1.

This is my solution with recursion:

```
change_state([], [], []).

change_state(X, [], []).

change_state(State, [H|T], NewState) :-
    functor(H, N, 1),
    arg(1, H, A),
    (    N = del 
    ->   remove_from_list(A, State, NewState)
    ;    arg(1, H, A),
         add_to_list(A, State, NewState) ),
    print(NewState),
    change_state(NewState, T, X),
    print(NewState).
```

I also put some prints into the function for debugging.

Now the problem:

If I call the function with

```
change_state([milled, burned], [del(burned), add(lol), add(hi)], L).
```

I get as an result

```
L = [milled].
```

So only the first predicate in L2 worked.

But the prints show me:

```
[milled][lol,milled][hi,lol,milled][hi,lol,milled][lol,milled][milled].
```

So it actually worked, but because of the recursion it goes back to the first state.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `change_state(State, [H|T], NewState) :- ...` shouldn't that be `change_state(State, [H|T], X) :- ...` considering your almost-tail-recursive call `change_state(NewState, T, X)`?

Comment: @RuudHelderman just tried it but now my return list is empty.

Comment: Clause `change_state(X, [], []).` must be replaced with `change_state(X, [], X)`.

Comment: Combining both of your answers worked! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your code is already working correctly with the modifications that were indicated in the comments, I think a clearer implementation would be as follows:

```
change_state(State, Changes, NewState) :-
    change_state_loop(Changes, State, NewState).

% Reverse the order of the first two arguments to avoid choice points.

change_state_loop([], State, State).
change_state_loop([Change|Changes], State, NewState) :-
    do(Change, State, PartiallyUpdatedState),
    change_state_loop(Changes, PartiallyUpdatedState, NewState).

% Use unification to choose the correct operation to perform.

do(del(Fluent), State, NewState) :- subtract(State, [Fluent], NewState).
do(add(Fluent), State, NewState) :- union(State, [Fluent], NewState).
```

Comment: Or in the presence of foldl, `change_state(State, Changes, NewState) :- foldl(do, Changes, State, NewState).`

Comment: @RuudHelderman Nice! I really like the solution based on `foldl/4`. However, I think using `foldl/4` makes the code more concise, not necessarily clearer (for beginners, of course).